# Change directory of css in patternlab

Tags: php, sass, patternlab.io

I want to change the directory of the `style.css` file in the pattern lab setup, how and where do I do this? I have a whole booststrap sass project setup already and I want patternlab to use the current files for this projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css and javascript files in the following file: 
source/_patterns/00-meta/_00-head.mustache